# Limit as $(x,y) \to 0$ of $x^2/y$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

If transform it into polar coordinates we get that:
$\lim_{r \rightarrow0}\frac{r^2 \cos^2(\theta)}{r\sin(\theta)}=\lim_{r \rightarrow0}r \frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$ which should be $0$ but then if we approach it from the curve $y=x^2$ we get $1$, but how is this the case? I thought using polar coordinates and showing the limit exists without being dependent on $\theta$ meant the limit exists but clearly it does not?

Comment: When you use polar coordinates, you assume that $x$ and $y$ approaches $0$ with the same speed. (You take the same $r$ for both of them.)

Comment: Hm, I was under the impression that polar coordinates are fool proof but I understand what you mean. Is there a way to know when polar coordinates won't work like above?

Comment: I observe that along the curve $y = x^2$, as $r \rightarrow 0$, $\theta \rightarrow 0$, so $\sin(\theta) \rightarrow 0$.  This means you have two zeroes in your denominator, not just the one from $r$.  (In fact, we should always be on the lookout for denominators that can be zero...)

Comment: Problem is that $\theta$ can depend on $r$ otherwise you're basically only looking at straight lines.